# why is "print(strOne is strTwo)" = True in the following problem?

Tags: python

Select the correct output of the following String operations

```
strOne = str("pynative")
strTwo = "pynative"
print(strOne == strTwo)
print(strOne is strTwo)
```

I thought it would be True,False because while it == the same "value", it *is* NOT referring to the same code in memory, right? or am I just missing something obvious or misunderstanding something basic?)

Comment: try this print(id(strOne), id(strTwo))

Comment: You’re not missing anything obvious.  As a CPython *implementation detail*, the bytecode compiler can ‘choose’ to optimise the code by assigning string values which are equal to the same memory address. And since the `is` operator is an *identity check*; this is likely the ‘choice’ the compiler has made.

Comment: nevermind, I finally found my answer RIGHT after posting this.  At least I think so, correct me if I am wrong but I am seeing that it is because strings are immutable and so both of these are in fact stored in same memory in a way to save space by Python, whereas when same problem but lists instead, they ARE mutable, so they are treated differently and it would instead be True,False.

Comment: oops, now I see the answer comments, they loaded late lol. Thank you both :)

Comment: sorry I have never used Stack Echange and just created this account to ask this question so I am still trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this particular compiler optimisation is an *implementation detail*; not a design feature and should not be relied upon.  Save yourself some headache and brain scratching and use the appropriate operator.  :-)